# Azure Web App vs Web Site

Tags: azure, website, web-applications

I am just starting to learn about Azure and I understand the difference between Web Sites, Cloud Services and VM's.

However in my Azure portal I can only see Web Apps and not Web Sites. Is this the same thing?  If not what is the difference and how do I deploy to an environment that has the same characteristics of a traditional Web Site as explained in all the online documentation.

Answer (score 7):

With the [Azure App Service announcement](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/24/announcing-azure-app-service/) Web Sites were renamed to Web Apps.  [Here's](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/whats-new-with-azure-app-service/) a list of old and new service names as well as changes introduced with App Services.

Comment: What happened to web roles?  Are they now web apps, or logic apps?

Comment: Web and worker roles (aka Cloud Services) still exist, although they lag a bit behind App Services in supporting new features.  [Here's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/) a comparison and guidance around choosing the best fit for your app.

Comment: Thanks!  If you happen to know if Web Apps can open a standard socket or not that would be great.  I'm referring to a plain old TCP socket, not a Websocket.  In olden days only web role could do that, not lightweight web sites, so I chose a web role.  That's the main thing I'll need to do and in a performant fashion in my upgraded project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible with web apps.